# Unit Testing to multiple RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, c#-4.0

I'm new in this of unit testing, and i need help with this code. It's working with MVC 4.0 but have some call to a database, and I don't understand how I can start to create the unit testing if I need to open a connection, I hope you can help me.

This is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(User user, IEnumerable<int> Groups)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(SecurityManager.COOKIENAME);
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            if (SecurityManager.HasPermission(int.Parse(cookie.Values.Get("Id")),(int)PermissionEnum.AddUser))
            {
                List<Group> gs = new List<Group>();
                if (Groups != null)
                {
                    foreach (int g in Groups)
                    {
                        Group gr = GroupManager.getGroup(g);
                        gs.Add(gr);
                    }
                }

                user.Groups = gs;

                if (UserManager.addUserEmployee(user))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.groups = new MultiSelectList(
                        GroupManager.getMyGroups(int.Parse(cookie.Values.Get("Id"))),"Id", "Name", Groups);
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Error saving the user.");
                    return View(user);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("NoPermission", "Home");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Home");
        } 
    }
```

How can I test what `RedirectToAction` is because I have more than one?

Answer (score 1):

To test RedirectToAction results, simply cast the result to a RedirectToRouteResult as follows:

```
// test case 1: 
RedirectToRouteResult result = controller.AddUser(user, groups) as RedirectToRouteResult;

Assert.Equal("NoPermission", result.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.Equal("Home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);

// test case 2:
RedirectToRouteResult result = controller.AddUser(user, groups) as RedirectToRouteResult;

Assert.Equal("Logout", result.RouteValues["action"]);
Assert.Equal("Home", result.RouteValues["controller"]);
```

Comment: And what about the data base connection? it doesn't matter?

Comment: Hey @blorkfish when i add the
    result.RouteValues["action"]); is displayed this error
    cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type 'system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary' 
do you know why?